# mi duda es acerca de java swing

Tags: java

mi  duda es acerca de del posicionamiento de los botones y otros elementos en java swing.

para posicionar algo sabemos que se puede utilizar el metodo setLocation(x,y);  usando pixeles.

pero realmente como informatico me cuesta bastante tratar de posicionar un solo elemento de una app de escritorio a traves de pixeles. hay alguna forma o herramienta que te ayude con la parte de pixeles?

por que pregunto esto? por que hace que el desarrollo sea super tedioso el tener que adivinar cual es el pixel exacto x,y. me gustaria saber si hay algun metodo mas actualizado o mejor para desarrollar apps de escritorio?

Comment: Échale un ojo a https://www.miglayout.com/. Es lo que usamos en mi laburo para los proyectos  que aún usan Swing...

Comment: en stackoverflow me catalogan esta duda como un -1 . pero realmente cuando quiero posicionar un boton en un lugar en concreto. me cuesta bastante el saber cual es el pixel exacto para llevar el boton a ese lugar. hay alguna forma de hacerlo mas sencillo?

Comment: Estás buscando opiniones porque no estás planteando un problema específico y terminas pidiendo recomendaciones. Eso cabe dentro de lo que puede recibir un voto negativo e incluso puede terminar cerrada como está
https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo

Answer (score 3):

En Swing, y previamente en AWT existe los "Layout" que permiten organizar los componentes.

Por ejemplo con `GridLayout` al agregar un componente al contendor este va ocupando las celdas de una matriz (el constructor recibe la cantidad de filas y columnas en las que se dividirá el contenedor)

Con `BorderLayout` los componentes se agregan en posiciones relativas del contenedor, por ejemplo en la parte de arriba (`PAGE_START`) o en la parte derecha (`LINE_END`)

Es importante que para diagramar una interfaz se pueden usar jerarquías de contenedores y componentes, por ejemplo: Para agregar una botonera inferior, el contenedor principal utiliza `BorderLayout` y se agrega un contenedor para la botonera en `PAGE_END` (abajo), luego este contenedor botonera ocupa `FlowLayout` (despliega los elementos en el orden que se agregan al contenedor) y agregas los botones en el.

Para mas información y ejemplos de uso, la documentación de Oracle respecto de los `LayoutManagers` esta en: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score -1):

Al igual que tu tambien empece con java swing pero hoy en dia si lo consideran algo obsoleto, a tu pregunta de otras tecnologias para apps de escritorio me imagino usando java, esta java FX tiene mejoras en la interface dandote control en el css y demas pero yo te recomendaria algo mas usado con mayor porcentaje de comunidad como lo es Spring boot con thymeleaf o un framawork para front end como Angular...

Comment: angular es web.. y aca pregunto especificamente para escritorio... no?

Comment: Esta es la zona de respuestas, no de comentarios. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios. Lee [answer].